# Parameters file: Template validation failed: Required property 'type' not found in JSON

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Using ARM template from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/azure-marketplace/7.6.0/src/mainTemplate.json

Created a parameters file (snippet only, more params in actual) for ARM template deployment thru terraform:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json##",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "_artifactsLocation": {
      "value": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/azure-marketplace/7.6.0/src/"
    },
    "_artifactsLocationSasToken": {
      "value": ""
    },
    "esVersion": {
      "value": "${esVersion}"
    },
    "esClusterName": {
      "value": "${esClusterName}"
    },
    "loadBalancerType": {
      "value": "external"
    },
    "loadBalancerInternalSku": {
      "value": "Basic"
    }
  }
}
```

Error message: Template validation failed: Required property 'type' not found in JSON. Path 'parameters._artifactsLocation', line 7, position 5."

Do we need to specify the property "type" in parameters file?

Answer (score 0):

no, fix this:

```
"_artifactsLocation": {
    "value": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/azure-marketplace/7.6.0/src/"
},
```

Comment: changed to above, still issue persists.

Comment: you need type in the template, not in the parameters file

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

The below params are not needed:

```
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json##",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
```

After removing them, no more template validation failures. Some parameters files don't need these headers.

reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/482

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue when edited template via Azure portal. Edition and save caused an error:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 11:31:50 PM - Error: Code=DeploymentPreflightValidationFailed; Message=The template is invalid. Error: 'Required property '$schema' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 2.'
```

To resolve it I downloaded the template manually, edited the json via text editor and saved it as a file. With manual saving - all runs with no errors.

When compared 2 files: 1st saved manually and 2nd via Azure portal I found significant difference.

Looks like a bug in the portal work.